# In Order and Pre Order Traversal of Binary Search Tree without recursion in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Question:
Write C functions to perform the following operations on the Binary Search Tree:

Deletetion of a given integer from Binary Search Tree.
Inorder traversal without recursion.
Preorder traversal without recursion.
( Use of global pointer is not allowed)

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct x
{
    int data;
    struct x* left;
    struct x* right;
}node;
node* createNode(int n)
{
    node* newNode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data=n;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}
node* insertion(node* root, int n)
{
    if(root==NULL) return createNode(n);
    else if(n < root->data) root->left=insertion(root->left,n);
    else if(n > root->data) root->right=insertion(root->right,n);
    return root;
}
int search(node* root, int key)
{
    if (root==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        if (key<root->data)
            search(root->left,key);
        else if(key>root->data)
            search(root->right,key);
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
node* deletion(node* root, int n)
{
    if (root==NULL) return root;
    if (n<root->data)
        root->left=deletion(root->left,n);
    else if (n>root->data)
        root->right=deletion(root->right,n);
    else
    {
        if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            node* temp=root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            node* temp=root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        node* temp=root->right;
        while (temp&&temp->left!=NULL)
            temp=temp->left;
        root->data=temp->data;
        root->right=deletion(root->right,temp->data);
    }
    return root;
}
void display(node* root,int n)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        display(root->right,n+5);
        for (int i = 0; i < n+2; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("/\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("%d\n",root->data,n+5);
        for (int i = 0; i < n+2; i++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("\\\n");
        display(root->left,n+5);
    }
}
int nodes(node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + nodes(root->left) + nodes(root->right);
}
void inorder(node* root)
{
    
}
void preorder(node* root) 
{ 
    
}
int main()
{
    int ch;
    node* root=NULL;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n1. INSERTION OF INTEGER\n");
        printf("2. DELETION OF INTEGER\n");
        printf("3. DISPLAY TREE\n");
        printf("4. IN-ORDER TRAVERSAL\n");
        printf("5. PRE-ORDER TRAVERSAL\n");
        printf("6. EXIT\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch==1)
        {
            int n;
            printf("Please enter an element: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            root=insertion(root,n);
            printf("%d inserted in BINARY SEARCH TREE.\n",n);
        }
        else if(ch==2)
        {
            int n;
            printf("Please enter the element to be deleted: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            root=deletion(root,n);
            printf("%d deleted from BINARY SEARCH TREE.\n",n);
        }
        else if(ch==3)
        {
            printf("\n");
            display(root,1);
        }
        else if(ch==4)
        {
            printf("\n     IN-ORDER\n");
            inorder(root);
        }
        else if(ch==5)
        {
            printf("\n     PRE-ORDER\n");
            preorder(root);
        }
        else if(ch==6)
        {
            printf("Exitting Program, Thank You.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("INVALID CHOICE! TRY AGAIN\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have done deletion, but couldn't figure out how to do inorder and pre order using iterative loops, if anyone could help out please help me.

Comment: The issue is how to keep track of where you are in the traversal, since you can't use recursion to do it for you.  Can you identify, as precisely as possible, what you need to keep track of?

Comment: @ScottHunter You started helping according to the compromise desribed here, didn't you? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Yunnosch: It would appear so.

Comment: when you can modify the definition of a tree node, you can add a pointer to the parent node and use this to traverse back.

Comment: The title and question are not the same. Is in order traversal part of this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

The reason recursions is so natural for performing depth-first searches is because you can easily return/backtrack to an earlier state and explore different branches. The compiler achieves this by using a stack of states consisting of parameters and local variables. Replacing recursion can therefore be achieved by using a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive in order traversal can be performed by modifying and later restoring the links using a method like Morris Traversal. Assuming this is a homework assignment, I assume you are supposed to attempt to implement this yourself before looking up an existing algorithm such as Morris Traversal. So at this point, the hint of modifying the links may be enough to allow you to implement a solution.